# pointers and linked list in C- unexpected behavior of program

Tags: c, list, function, pointers

I recently started programming in C, and I've been working in a linked list program for a while. Now, the program is about having a profile in which you will register movies you watch and then save them in a .txt file. the trouble comes with the movie getting into the list. when I try to print it, the fields will show empty, as if I weren't assigning the pointers properly, but the fact is that the program KNOWS that I stacked a movie in my profile. I know it's a hard question to ask, any help would be appreciated. I'll show here the Insertmovie function, where I think there might be the problem, and the moviecopy function(I tested that function and does not work itself, although I doubt I did something wrong there):

```
int stacknewmovie (movie* p, list* l){
    if(!p || !l){
        return 0;
    }
    node* n;
    n=newnode();
    if(!n){
        return 0;
    }
    insertnodeinfo(n, p);
    n->next=NULL;
    if(l->first==NULL){
        l->first=n;
        return 1;
    }else{
        n->next=l->first;
        l->first=n;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here the moviecopy:

```
int moviecopy(movie* pel2,movie* pel1){
    if(!pel1 || !pel2){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        pel2=pel1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Again, thanks for taking your time. I didn't know how to show my problem better, as the compiler doesn't even warns me about anything.

```
node* insertnodeinfo(node* n, movie* p){
    if(!p || !n){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        moviecopy(n->info, p);
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Listed link"? Surely you mean "linked list"?

Comment: Is it not? the structure  is list{ node* first};

Comment: I just found out what you ment, the title was wrong. changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
int stacknewmovie (movie* p, list* l){
if(!p || !l){
   return 0; 
}
 node* n;
 n=newnode();
if(!n){
  return 0;
}
insertnodeinfo(n, p);
n->next=NULL;
if(l->first==NULL){
    l->first=node;                 //problem here replace "node" by "n"??
    return 1;
}else{
    n->next=l->first;
    l->first=n;
    return 1;
}
```

as I did in the comment replace "node" by "n" first (I suppose that you want to write "n" not "node")

Comment: my apologies, the code was half-written in spanish so i changed it, forgot that one. It's fine in my code, no errors nor warnings

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a linked list because:

```
n->next=l->first; //this made the list a circular linked list 
l->first=n;       //Here is the problem I think
```

Because always the new node becomes the first node in the list, Is this that you want?

Comment: Thaks for the replies! Sorry, my native language is not english, so "linked list" might not be the proper term. yes, I don't care about the order of the list, so I just insert it always at the beggining. How is that a problem then?

Comment: Also, a circular linked list should have the last node pointing to the first, right? Mine points to NULL, if I am correct. I don't change where it points unless the list is not empty so the last node always keeps NULL, I think.

Comment: Only if the list is empty, but in else statement you put `n->next=l->first;` then the 'last' node points to the first node. Can you show insertnodeinfo(n,p) code?

Comment: Sure, I'll post it right now. Anyway, I'm sorry I am not getting it. Do you mean "n" is the last node, so it points to the first? I thought n would be the first node in the list, not the last... Again, thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: How do you call stacknewmovie?

Comment: I just call it after filling its fields:                              `stacknewmovie(p,getprofilelist(profile));`

Comment: I don't think the problem is how I call that function. Here I call only moviecopy after filling the fields:                `moviecopy(paux, p);
               printf("\nTitle:%s",getmovietitle(paux));
               printf("\nAuthor:%s",getmovieauthor(paux));
               printf("\nRelease date: %d/%d/%d", getmoviereleaseday(paux),getmoviereleasemonth(paux),getmoviereleaseyear(paux));
               printf("\nDate watched: %d/%d/%d", getmoviedateday(paux),getmoviedatemonth(paux),getmoviedateyear(paux));
               printf("\nValoration:%d", getmovieval(paux));
              `

Comment: If i don't use moviecopy and just print the movie I just filled, it works. But copying that movie and printing the copy causes it to show empty.